# Errow while installing nfs-kernel-server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install nfs-kernel-server by following command:

```
apt install -y nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

And it fails with this error:

```
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried what I gave found on forums:

```
apt remove -y rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server keyutils libtirpc1
```

and

```
apt remove nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

But without any success, always fails.

This is fresh hardened image. I have also flushed iptables and commented hosts.deny to be sure is not that.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
apt purge -y rpcbind
apt install -y nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: Don't do the `purge`, at least not before backing up `/etc/exports`.